# Jsc3d: How to rotate, scale, move stl objects?

Tags: javascript, jsc3d

Can someone explain, write, how to reach mesh vertices using jsc3d,
and then move each vertice so stl object can rotate. Especially, I would like to see Matrix3x4 with realistic numbers in it ? If You can move vertices for particular angle it would be perfect ! Thank You!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I only have code that is provided on jsc3d, on git hub, and there is written general Matrix3x4, and I have idea how it should work. Also I know using cos and sin functions to rotate 2d coord system (using polar coords), but thats all I can do. I really need some help first to reach vertices and then to rotate using matrix3x4, and in 3d :)

Comment: at this time, jsc3d don't include yet handling for a single mesh, you must expand it by writing your own mesh scale/translate/rotation routines.for meshes, but you can zoom/pan/rotate the whole world (e.g. group of loaded meshes),